# How do I redeem NieR: Automata without a cd drive

Tags: nier-automata

I had bought NieR: Automata from my local gaming store and I don't have a cd drive, Is it possible to redeem it in any other way?

Comment: unless you got a a slip a with redeem code which tells you how to redeem it take the game back and get your Disk(s)

Comment: @Memor-X Did you read my question properly? Because I have the disc. I want to redeem the game and I don't have a disc drive

Comment: ahhhh, my apologies. i must have read drive as disk when you talk about redeeming because generally if you buy a disk you don't do any redeeming at all. i've only ever came across 1 game in my entire life which came with a disk and had an online redeem code but it was in a Collector's Edition. still, if there isn't a slip with a redeem code and instructions i doubt there's another way

Comment: Sometimes you can input the product key into Steam.  https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you don't. You don't meet the requirements to install physical media.

Sometimes, games come with a, "redeem code" that you can use to register the game in Steam, Origin, or the like. That allows you to install the game digitally. If the physical disk doesn't come with that, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. Your only options are:

1. Install a disk drive. Install game from disk. You will need the disk in the drive in order to play.
2. Return the game, buy a digital version.

Comment: External disc drives are available as well.  They should connect via USB.

Comment: Sometimes it can also be a manufacturer/packaging fault that causes the disks to come without the redeem code. Had this happen personally. I'd take it back to the store with the receipt, but first get them to check another copy before getting my cash back (get them to swap it or simply open up another store copy and look for a redeem code)